# I want to replace NaN value in one column, but my other column is condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with replacing NaN values in my DataFrame

I am using Data from Kaggle and I want to do the project.
I found correlation between two columns.
I want to replace my NaN value in column 'VIP' to be 0, only if in the column 'HomePlanet' is value Earth. How to do that?

I hope you understand my question, thx.

Answer (score 2):

```
df.loc[ (df.HomePlanet == 'Earth') & (df.VIP == NaN), 'VIP'] = 0
```

Comment: The problem with your suggestion is that my NaN is not defined so the program won't replace it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this:

```
df.loc[df.HomePlanet == "Earth", "VIP"] = df.fillna(0)
```

Comment: Yeah, that is the answer l needed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can switch to numpy very easily :

```
VIP = df['VIP'].to_numpy()
HP = df['HomePlanet'].to_numpy()
VIP[HP == 'Earth'] = 0
df['VIP'] = VIP
```